# text file format from array

Tags: python

I have no: of arrays, and i like to take it to text file in specific format, for eg.,

'present form'

```
a= [1 2 3 4 5 ]

b= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]  

c= [ 8 9 10 12 23 43 45 56 76 78]

d= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 45 56 76 78 12 23 43 ]
```

The 'required format' in a txt file,

```
   a   '\t'    b      '\t'     d  '\t'    c

   1   '\t'    1  

   2    '\t'   2  

   3    '\t'   3  

   4    '\t'   4  

   5   '\t'    5  

      6   

      7              

      8
```

`'\t'`- 1 tab space

problem is,

I have the array in linear form[a],[b],[c],and d, i have to transpose('required format') and sort [a],[b],[d],and [c] and write it as a txt file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for fun with no imports:

```
a= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c= [8, 9, 10, 12, 23, 43, 45, 56, 76, 78]
d= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 56, 76, 78, 12, 23, 43]

fh = open("out.txt","w")

# header line
fh.write("a\tb\td\tc\n")
# rest of file
for i in map(lambda *row: [elem or "" for elem in row], *[a,b,d,c]):
  fh.write("\t".join(map(str,i))+"\n")

fh.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But how to write with 'header' i mean
 'a'<tab>'b'<tab>'c'<tab>'d' #header ?
1<tab>1<tab>1<tab>8  # its working perfect
2<tab>2<tab>2<tab>9  # its working perfect

* How to specify headlines/header?

Comment: @pear, added the header line.  @nosklo, does the addition of the izip_longest function for 2.5, make yours a little "uglier" and "unreadable"?  I agree my performance it probably worse.

Answer (score 6):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import csv
import itertools



a= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c= [8, 9, 10, 12, 23, 43, 45, 56, 76, 78]
d= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 56, 76, 78, 12, 23, 43]

with open('destination.txt', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    cf.writerow(['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']) # header  
    cf.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(a, b, d, c))
```

Results on `destination.txt` (*`<tab>`s* are in fact real tabs on the file):

```
a<tab>b<tab>d<tab>c
1<tab>1<tab>1<tab>8
2<tab>2<tab>2<tab>9
3<tab>3<tab>3<tab>10
4<tab>4<tab>4<tab>12
5<tab>5<tab>5<tab>23
<tab>6<tab>6<tab>43
<tab>7<tab>7<tab>45
<tab>8<tab>8<tab>56
<tab><tab>45<tab>76
<tab><tab>56<tab>78
<tab><tab>76<tab>
<tab><tab>78<tab>
<tab><tab>12<tab>
<tab><tab>23<tab>
<tab><tab>43<tab>
```

Here's the izip_longest function, if you have python < 2.6:

```
def izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None):
    def sentinel(counter=([fillvalue]*(len(iterables)-1)).pop):
        yield counter()
    fillers = itertools.repeat(fillvalue)
    iters = [itertools.chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) 
             for it in iterables]
    try:
        for tup in itertools.izip(*iters):
            yield tup
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: The OP wants a slightly different order than a,b,c,d. You might want to edit your answer accordingly. Otherwise, +1

Comment: @Mark Pim: Seems straightforward on how to change order. However I changed the order to a,b,d,c to better suit the question.

Comment: I think he wants numbers that don't match any other numbers on the list to be alone on their own line, in ascending order.

Comment: @Hooked: I'm not sure why he would want that. The question doesn't say that and have no examples of that behaviour. If he wants that he should update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at matplotlib.mlab.rec2csv and csv2rec:

```
>>> from matplotlib.mlab import rec2csv,csv2rec
# note: these are also imported automatically when you do ipython -pylab

>>> rec = csv2rec('csv file.csv')
>>> rec2csv(rec, 'copy csv file', delimiter='\t')
```